# How to find timespan in milliseconds between two times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, timespan

Using TSQL how do you find the difference between two times, in milliseconds?

```
declare @start datetime = '2012-04-10 14:59:12.863',
    @end datetime = '2012-04-10 14:59:13.800'

select  @start, @end, 'TODO: get timespan in milliseconds between @start and @end'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the datediff function as [documented here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
declare @start datetime = '2012-04-10 14:59:12.863',     
    @end datetime = '2012-04-10 14:59:13.800'     

select datediff(ms, @start, @end)
```

The ms is the datepart abbreviation for milliseconds.